# Admin interface menu not showing

Tags: administrator, user-groups

I created a new usergroup (Administrator) to allow access to the backend, only to specific components in Joomla 3.7.2.
These are the settings in Global Config for this group:

[image]

However, when a user belonging to this group logs in to admin, this is what she gets:

[image: The top] menu and admin dashboard are gone!

How do I get this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, what did you set as the  Group Parent * when you created this group?

Comment: Yes, I set Public as parent

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to allow access to the module for the Admin Menu for this usergroup.

Quite simple... :-)